# How to pass in multiple `--data` in Ansible using `uri` module?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to come up with equivalent Curl command in Ansible using the `uri` module to no avail

```bash
curl 'https://URL --data 'a=1234' --data 's=4321'
```

In Ansible:

```yaml
- uri:
    url: https://URL
    method: PUT
    body:
      a: 1234
      s: 4321
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I get a response back that command is invalid meaning my Ansible task doesn't work but using the equivalent `curl` command works fine.

Comment: Can you share the ansible error with `-vvv` mode ? Also the default format for body is ram. The url is accepting raw format or json ?

Comment: I got it working by changing adding body_format: form-urlencoded and removed the headers

Comment: @hitman222 Please add your successful outcome as an answer and then accept it, so others will see it, since not everyone reads the comments

Answer (score 0):

> ***I got it working by changing adding `body_format: form-urlencoded` and removed the `headers`***

Accoridng the documentation [curl `-d, --data <data>`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d)

> *... in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This makes `curl` pass the data to the server using the `content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.*

as well [`uri` module – Interacts with webservices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) and [Parameter: `body_format`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-body_format)

> *or `form-urlencoded`, encodes the body argument, if needed, and automatically sets the Content-Type header accordingly.*

```yaml
- name: 'https://example.com'
  uri:
    url: 'https://example.com'
    method: PUT # or POST
    body:
      a: '1234'
      s: '4321'
    body_format: form-urlencoded
  register: result
```